# iOS keyboard with "Join", go to another view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, view, storyboard

I want the *Join* keyboard button to switch to another view with the following code:

```
PurseTab *CustomViewControllerScreen =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detail"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CustomViewControllerScreen
                                     animated:YES];
```

If i click on button nothing happens.

P.S. I'm using Storyboard.

Comment: Can you show the crash backtrace? There's not enough information here.

Answer (score 1):

If the error says `Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'Detail'`, then it's pretty likely that the storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with the identifier `Detail`.  You may think you set the view controller's identifier to `Detail` in the storyboard, but perhaps you really didn't, or you are testing an old version of the app.

You need to make sure that the Identifier field in the View Controller section of the Attributes Inspector says `Detail`, with correct capitalization and no extra whitespace.

Although... if the error message really says `Storyboard ()` then that's pretty suspicious too.  It should say something like `Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0xb65e570>)`.